# Surface view and scaling

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-layout-weight

Before all, I apologies for my English.

I'm a newbie in programming of Android App and I recently discovered the Canvas and Bitmap, so I decided to make a "Game" that can only use landscape. I discovered too the SurfaceView and how implement a background on my SurfaceView, but the first of all is that my background is an image 496x288.

I was searching in internet to learn how I can scaled well to fill all the screen of my phone with the background, and another screens. So I find this code and try to use in my app.

```
@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fondo1escalado);
            float scale = (float) background.getHeight() / (float) getHeight();
            int newWidth = Math.round((background.getWidth() / scale));
            int newHeight = Math.round(background.getHeight() / scale);
            scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, newWidth, newHeight, true);
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
            gameLoopThread.start();


}

@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, 0,0, null);
}
```

It works, but it doesn't work well. I got this:

[image] (Don't worry about the character)

It scales well but don't fit all the screen (See the blue background).

So, like a good programmer I try to fix this using a GUI that I have designed wich dimensions are 296x912, I used the same code, and it scalates well in the Height but not in the Width for all the screens even a tablet.

[image]

This is the code of the GUI

```
float scalaInterfazAltura = (float) interfaz.getHeight() / (float) getHeight();
        int newHeightInterfaz = Math.round(interfaz.getHeight() / scalaInterfazAltura);
        int newWidthInterfaz = Math.round(interfaz.getWidth() / scalaInterfazAltura);
        scaledinterfaz = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(interfaz, newWidthInterfaz, newHeightInterfaz, true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(scaledinterfaz, getWidth() - interfaz.getWidth()/2, 0, null);
```

So, my question is: There is a thing to scale well in Surfaceview? I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens cause Your display height more than View height. 
Try to use `surfaceView.getHeight()` instead of `interfaz.getHeight()`.

Also You can use

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in Your Activity before `setContentView()` to make Your game fullscreen.

Comment: Really apreciated. FIrst I don't know what do you mean with surfaceView.getHeight() (I don't know if I have to initialize a Surface variable or what) so I use requestWindosFeature and it works very well. Thank you so much.